# How do delete wallet with blank walletname?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, wallet.dat

I seem to have created a blank wallet at some point that looks like this:

```
bitcoin-cli listwallets
[
  "",
  "mainwallet"
]
```

How can I delete the `""` wallet?

It doesn't seem to have its own folder as per [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116531/how-to-delete-a-specific-wallet-in-bitcoind), so I'm not sure how to remove it.

I would be happy to remove all wallets and start afresh, but `bitcoind` won't start if I delete all the wallet folders (i.e. `/mainwallet/` and `/wallet.dat`).